# Calling a php file by using mysql trigger

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to call .php by using mysql trigger.This is the code of mysql

```
delimiter $$     
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS qwertyuiop$$      
CREATE TRIGGER qwertyuiop    
AFTER UPDATE ON testing
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN    
 DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);    
 DECLARE result int(10);    
 SET cmd=CONCAT('C:/wamp/www/index.php');    
 SET result = sys_exec(cmd);    
END    
@@     
Delimiter;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You simply can't do this. There is no mechanism for MySQL to call PHP like this, in a trigger or anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

Even though it's technically possible with the help of `lib_mysqludf_sys` library you **shouldn't be doing this**. It's wrong in all possible ways. To mention just a few:

1. Using these UDFs on its own is a **huge** security threat. Here is a short quote from the lib's documentation:

   > Be very careful in deciding whether you need this function. UDFs are
   >   available to all database users - you cannot grant EXECUTE privileges
   >   for them. As the commandstring passed to sys_exec can do pretty much
   >   everything, **exposing the function poses a very real security hazard**.
   >   Even for a benign user, it is possible to accidentally do a lot of
   >   damage with it. The call will be executed with the privileges of the
   >   os user that runs MySQL, so it is entirely feasible to delete MySQL's
   >   data directory, or worse.
2. Doing any non-transactional operations in a trigger are wrong. Data changes made by DML statement (in your case it's an update) can be and will be rolled back in a real world scenario. You won't be able to undo calls to your php script.
3. You're prolonging the time for update transaction possibly causing lock-wait-timeouts for other update/insert operations.

Recommended reading:

- [The Trouble with Triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)

---

Now even if we set aside everything mentioned above you have several issues with your code

1. You change `DELIMITER` to `$$` but then terminate a trigger definition with `@@`.
2. There is no need for `cmd` variable.
3. A trigger is executed in a context of an OS user under which MySQL is running therefore you have to provide **absolute paths** both to the php executable and a php script

That being said a working version might look like

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER qwertyuiop    
AFTER UPDATE ON testing
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN    
  DECLARE result INT;    
  SET result = sys_exec('C:/php/php.exe C:/path/to/script.php');     
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```