# Call WCF Service from MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, web-services, database-trigger, mysql-udf

I have two databases on two different servers. I need to sync. data using service on the second server. The problem is I want to call this service from MySQL trigger. 
I have read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger) , [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127943/connect-to-web-service-api-in-mysql) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437759/calling-a-php-file-by-using-mysql-trigger?lq=1) too but could not find it useful for my problem.

I have found a more useful link [open-bi.blogspot.com/2012/11/…](http://open-bi.blogspot.com/2012/11/call-restful-web-services-from-mysql.html) it provides a library for mysql to perform my task.

Now the problem domain gets shortened and my problem becomes how to install this library on windows.

Comment: What is your actual problem here?

Comment: Problem is how do I call a web url/service from mysql trigger

Comment: I have found a more useful link http://open-bi.blogspot.com/2012/11/call-restful-web-services-from-mysql.html it provides a library for mysql to perform my task.

Comment: Now the problem domain gets shortened and my problem becomes how to install this library on windows

Comment: I would recommend that you don't add details in comments but rather [edit] your question instead and add details there.